# checkbox post Inputs are dropped on submit after using jquery sortable

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-ui-sortable

My checkbox post Inputs are dropped on submit after using jquery sortable.

When the form submits I only lose the checked checkboxes that have been sorted with sortable. The unsorted inputs work fine. The closest I found was a post regarding a similar fixfox bug.

```
<form name="input" method="get">
    <table border="1">
        <tbody class="data" id="sortable">
            <tr>
                <td>row 1</td>
                <td><input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="batch_uploads_ids[162]" value="4|32" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 2</td>
                <td><input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="batch_uploads_ids[163]" value="0|45" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 3</td>
                <td><input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="batch_uploads_ids[164]" value="8|56" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

// Return a helper with preserved width of cells
var fixHelper = function (e, ui) {
    ui.children().each(function () {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
    });
    return ui;
};

$("#sortable").sortable({
    helper: fixHelper
}).disableSelection();


$("#sortable").live('hover', function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        //handle: 'button',
        cancel: ''
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

I have tried to recreate it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panhandle/uCED4/11/)

Comment: what u really need?will you explain it clearly.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have a table which I am sorting on it's rows. In each row I have a checkbox input. If I don't do any sorting then all works fine when I submit the form i.e. all ticked checkboxes are shown in the post variable e.g. batch_uploads_ids. However, if I sort any row (using sortable) then the sorted ticked input does not appear in the post variable. All the unsorted ones do still appear ok. It seems like the act of sorting detaches the specific input sorted? Is that any clearer?